# loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects: fails to connect button to an action in the controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm upgrading a very old application to XCode 12.0, and I find that `loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:` fails to connect my `onContinue:` method with my Continue button, when the deprecated method `loadNibName:owner:` connects the method with the button correctly.

Here's the code loading the nib:

```
- (void) loadNibNamed:(NSString*) nibName
{
    bool useDeprecatedLoadNib = false;
    if (useDeprecatedLoadNib) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self];
    } else {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName
                                      owner:self
                            topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjects];
    }
}
```

My nib has a Continue button, and this method in the controller:

```
- (IBAction)onContinue:(id)sender
```

When I set `useDeprecatedLoadNib=true`, everything works fine: I click on the Continue button and my `onContinue:` method is invoked.

When I set `useDeprecatedLoadNib=false`, the window appears, but when I click on the Continue button, nothing happens.

Using the debugger, I confirmed that the controller's `awakeFromNib:` and `init:` methods are being called, but `onContinue:` is never called.  I also tried setting `topLevelObjects:nil`, but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Doh.  I was passing a pointer to an NSMutableArray expecting it to be filled.  That's not how it works.  The following code works correctly:

```
- (void) loadNibNamed:(NSString*) nibName
{
    bool useDeprecatedLoadNib = false;
    if (useDeprecatedLoadNib) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self];
    } else {
        NSArray* nibObjects = nil;
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName
                                      owner:self
                            topLevelObjects:&nibObjects];
        [topLevelObjects addObjectsFromArray:nibObjects];
    }
}
```